# how to verify make build is actually parallel on windows?

Tags: c++, windows, makefile

I am using a proprietary, licensed compiler - QNX 6.5.0 SP1 in case it matters - and I want to verify that multiple instances of the compiler are allowed to be invoked during my build.

Yes, I'm invoking `make all -j8` but looking at my Windows Resource Monitor, it *appears* that only one **compiler.exe** is ever active at once whereas I can see multiple instances of **make.exe** active simultaneously; obviously this is not a robust method.

Question: how do I verify that multiple **compiler.exe** instances are active simultaneously?

GNU Make 3.81

Comment: What type of code are you compiling? How many files are there in the project you are compiling?

Comment: 4,692 .cpp files plus more boost .hpp files and .h files.

Comment: One quick hack test would be to attempt to compile two separate huge files simultaneously. A file with a static array of ten million elements ought to slow the compiler down enough to see if you have some sort of block on multiple simultaneous compiles.

Comment: You should specify which version of make you're using.

Answer (score 0):

I think the relevant for you might be how long the compilation takes, right? So the easiest IMHO would be to measure the time without and with the parallelization (the full build).

For Linux there is a pretty handy `time` command which can measure the time precisely. This is also available in GitBash console (when you install Git).

Other than that, on Windows the easiest way to measure time is to use this:

```
echo Start: %time% > timelog.log
make all -jX
echo End: %time% >> timelog.log
```

where X is the max. number of parallel commands. Put it to the batch file, run the full compilation from scratch once with `-j1` and then with `-j8` and compare the time differences. If the time is significantly shorter with `-j8`, then the compilation pretty surely runs in parallel.

Another thing to look onto is to check the CPU load - if the compiler runs in parallel, it usually exercises full 100% load of all the CPU cores (except for rare cases, when IO is slow, e.g. when having boost on a network drive). If only one CPU core is fully exercised and not the other cores, that usually means that the compilation does not run in parallel.

Comment: I've already measured it. It's 28 mins with and without `-j8` but this doesn't prove that there's a license limitation on the compilers. It could be the makefile I inherited is bad. idk. I need a rigorous method of detecting whether multiple instances of compiler are ever running.

Comment: Then try with the same make and a different compiler (MSVC, Mingw) if the results are the same or if there is a speedup in parallel compilation. If yes, that would prove that the make can run commands in parallel (which seems to be the case anyway, as you can see multiple make.exe in the task monitor). It could be, that the QNX compiler might have a global mutex which only allows to run a single instance at the time.